# Adding empty rows or space in fo:table inly if there's enough space for next data

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have something like this:

```
<fo:table>
    <fo:table-body>
        <xsl:for-each select ="1 to 1000">
            <fo:table-row height="10mm" line-height="10mm">
                <fo:table-cell>    
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

I need to insert empty row after each row with value, bu ONLY if there is enough space on current page for next row with value. So it would look like:

```
---------- page 1 -------------
1

2

3

4

5
---------- page 2 --------------
6

7

8

9

10
--------------------------------
```

If I just add empty fo:table-row it looks like:

```
---------- page 1 -------------
1

2

3

4

5
---------- page 2 --------------

6

7

8

9

---------- page 3 --------------
10
```

Comment: I do not understand the question, but if all you wish is "space" (you should never make space by inserting an empty row), then use some space-property on the cell/block inside the cell that enables what you wish (like padding-bottom).

Comment: @KevinBrown The problem is that you need to insert empty space selectively based on space left on the page for next row. If I'll add a block inside a cell the problem will be the same - block will be inserted always and will always add an empty space even when you don't need it.

Comment: In reading what you want I do not think you can accomplish it unless you know exactly the number of rows and use mod to apply different rules for rows 5, 10, ... If your row heights are irregular, this would not be possible. you cannot do positional formatting based on page-position in an FO engine (i.e. "if I am the last row on a page")

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can add 'padding-bottom' to each row except the last row in the table. You may end up with row 5 of your example being moved to the second page, but you can at least be sure that there's no extra space at the top of the page.